# sed-replacing and using a pattern with multi-lines

Tags: shell-script, sed, csv

I've a CSV file with multiple rows. I wanted to copy the same data multiple times and each time replacing a specific character with another character from a different file.

**Example**:

Below are two files, a csv and a ref file (containing A to Z) characters.
I wanted to copy the csv content 26 times (A to Z) and each time replacing the variable **VAR** with A,B,C,....Z.

cat csv_file

```
some text with VAR,data 2,data 3,data 4,some text and VAR
,,,data 4,some text
,,,data 4,some text
```

cat ref

```
A
B
C
...so on upto 
Z
```

Result:

```
some text with A,data 2,data 3,data 4,some text and A
,,,data 4,some text
,,,data 4,some text
some text with B,data 2,data 3,data 4,some text and B
,,,data 4,some text
,,,data 4,some text
..
... so on
```

what I'm doing is

```
DATA="some text with & following text,data 2,data 3,data4,some text and_&\n,,,data4,some text\n,,,data 4,some text"

sed -e "s/^.*$/$DATA/g" ref
```

Is there any other way of achieving the same result but with file name instead of variable (DATA)?

Answer (score 0):

Below command every time it replaces VAR with {A..Z}

Its working fine

```
for i in `cat /var/tmp/ref`; do  sed "s/VAR/$i/g" csv_file ;done
```

Sample output

```
some text with A,data 2,data 3,data 4,some text and A
,,,data 4,some text
,,,data 4,some text
some text with B,data 2,data 3,data 4,some text and B
,,,data 4,some text
,,,data 4,some text
```

Comment: or maybe use `while read -r i ; do ...`, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I've a question, I was trying with sed 's/VAR/$i/g' but it replaced VAR with "$i" instead of it's value. Is there a difference between double quotes and single quotes in sed?

Comment: Yes there is a difference . Always suggested to use double quotes.

Comment: Kindly vote for my answer

Comment: @PraveenKumarBS I'm new to this site, so I don't have the "power" to vote you.